# How to change to a different port for Java server in Netbeans to listen?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, reporting-services

I use Netbeans 6.7 to develop Java servlet. It defaults to port 8080. How do I change the port number to 8083 for example?

Comment: Hi, in the future when you consider to tag `servlet`, please choose `servlets` instead. Use the one with the most coverage (you can see the counts in the suggestion dropdown list). I've retagged `servlet` to `servlets` or removed it in your questions too often :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the port, using the property editors available on the Servers dialog.

Select the Servers item from the Tools menu.[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e8ed5c303e.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e8ed5c303e.png)

This image was captured from 6.8... but the dialog has been available (pretty much unchanged) since NetBeans 4.1.

Comment: Great, thanks, I didn't know you could attach images, wonderful !

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the servlet container or application server you are using.

In tomcat, for example, this is done by changing the `port` attribute of the  `Connector` for `HTTP/1.1` in `tomcat/conf/server.xml`. In other containers it would be similar to this - somewhere in the configurations.

Comment: Thanks. So there is nothing in the Netbeans GUI that I can change this setting ?

Comment: Do you use the web server shipping with Tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

1.Just search server.xml file in the conf directory [within  tomcat installation folder]

2.Search for content like following:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

1. change the port attribute to any other port number.

source:
http://ohmjavaclasses.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-change-port-number-of-tomcat.html

Answer (score 1):

1. GO to Tools > Servers.
2. Dialog box opens up
3. Change the port under "server port:"
   Try with incrementing or decrementing the portnumber if it still takes time to run the jsp page
4. Uninstall netbeans, glassfishserver, Tomcat open source code.
   then reinstall latest JAVA SE from the mother website [www.netbeans.org](http://www.netbeans.org).

Comment: Please format the answer properly, so that the poster can comprehend it easily. :)